# What is this 3-pin laptop-style power connector?

Tags: power-supply, connection

[image]

What are the pinouts on this power connector?

This is on an old industrial fanless PC from an unknown manufacturer. (A company called Welotec made a product with what appears to have been the same enclosure and heatsink, but a standard power connector.) For an age reference, it has a PS/2 keyboard connector and a CF card slot.

I know the power inputs might be labeled on the board, but I'm hoping to power it on without opening the case.

Answer (score 2):

Thats a GND,V5,V12 pinouts.

Not 100% sure the pin orientation now. I use to have a similar powersupply for a small dektop PC attached to the back of some PoS setups.